# React, render & console.log() displays different values when onInput event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i write in the input element, it triggers `onInputChange()` function, that updates `inputValue` state, then calls the `getValue()` that gets the `inputValue` state and log in console. The value that is rendered is not the same that is in console, what's happening here?

Reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-i4wprk?file=src%2FApp.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
    };
  }

  getValue = () => {
    const { inputValue } = this.state;
    console.log(inputValue);
  };

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({ inputValue });
    this.getValue();
  };

  render() {
    const { inputValue } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input placeholder="texto" onInput={this.onInputChange} />
        <p>{inputValue}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is because `this.setState` is asynchronous so when you do it and right after call `this.getValue()`, the data is not already set in the state

Comment: @OneQ there's a way to solve that?

Comment: You can use the callback : `this.setState({ inputValue }, () => this.getValue());`

Comment: Why does it matter what's logged in the console? Why are you even logging your state values?

Comment: @Phil this is just a reproducible example, i'm i'm debugging a code, the original function doesn't logs nothing in console.

Comment: Don't use `console.log()` for debugging. Use the debugger or relevant extensions like React Dev Tools

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is not a synchronous call so there is no guarantee that your console log will fire after the value has been updated in state.  You can add a callback to `setState`

```
this.setState({inputValue}, () => {this.getValue()}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`setState(nextState, callback?)`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate)

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.